# gulp build is raising this Error - [tslint] Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2'

Tags: development, nodejs, gulp, npm

I want to install this web part from hhttps://github.com/AsishP/SPFxWebParts , but when i run this command `gulp build` i got this error `Error - [tslint] Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2'`. here is my full cmd outputs. any advice please?

```
C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master>gulp clean
Build target: DEBUG
[16:46:55] Using gulpfile C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master\gulpfile.js
[16:46:55] Starting 'clean'...
[16:46:55] Starting gulp
[16:46:55] Starting subtask 'clean'...
[16:46:55] Finished subtask 'clean' after 3.54 ms
[16:46:55] Finished 'clean' after 7.32 ms
[16:46:55] ==================[ Finished ]==================
[16:46:56] Project with unknown name version:unknown
[16:46:56] Build tools version:3.17.11
[16:46:56] Node version:v14.17.0
[16:46:56] Total duration:3.07 s

C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master>
C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master>npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master\package.json'
npm WARN SPFxWebParts-master No description
npm WARN SPFxWebParts-master No repository field.
npm WARN SPFxWebParts-master No README data
npm WARN SPFxWebParts-master No license field.

up to date in 0.776s
found 0 vulnerabilities


C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master>
C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master>gulp build
Build target: DEBUG
[16:47:02] Using gulpfile C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master\gulpfile.js
[16:47:02] Starting 'build'...
[16:47:02] Starting gulp
[16:47:02] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
[16:47:02] Warning - [configure-sp-build-rig] Missing config.json file. If this is a non-web project, consider using a non-web build rig like @microsoft/sp-build-node
[16:47:02] Warning - [configure-sp-build-rig] This project is using an old config.json file version (undefined). Run the build again with the --upgrade (gulp --upgrade) flag to upgrade the config.json file to the latest version.
[16:47:02] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 2.89 ms
[16:47:02] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[16:47:02] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 113 ms
[16:47:02] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[16:47:02] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[16:47:02] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 15 ms
[16:47:02] Finished subtask 'sass' after 6.61 ms
[16:47:02] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[16:47:02] Error - [tslint] Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2'
Require stack:
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\RSCTask.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\TscCmdTask.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\index.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\index.js
- C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master\gulpfile.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
[16:47:02] Error - 'tslint' sub task errored after 5.9 ms
 Cannot find module '@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2'
Require stack:
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\RSCTask.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\TscCmdTask.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\index.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\index.js
- C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master\gulpfile.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
[16:47:02] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[16:47:02] Error - [tsc] Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2'
Require stack:
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\RSCTask.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\TscCmdTask.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\index.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\index.js
- C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master\gulpfile.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
[16:47:02] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 1.8 ms
 Cannot find module '@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2'
Require stack:
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\RSCTask.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\TscCmdTask.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-typescript\lib\index.js
- C:\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\index.js
- C:\SPFxWebParts-master\SPFxWebParts-master\gulpfile.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
[16:47:02] 'build' errored after 146 ms
[16:47:02]
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1
```

Comment: 1) What version of node.js are you using? 2) can you run `npm list -g --depth=0` and post the results?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov thanks for the reply .. here sis the result `+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.12.1
+-- gulp@4.0.2
`-- yo@4.3.0`

Comment: and what is the node version? can your run `node --version`?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov it is `v14.17.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a computability issue.

**SharePoint Framework (SPFx) 1.7.1 requires the following**

- node.js [LTS 8.x](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/)
- npm v5, v6
- yeoman yo@3.1.1. (for creating new projects only)

**This is what you have. It won't work**

- node.js v14.17.0
- npm: v6 (guessing here)
- yeoman yo@4.3.0. (for creating new projects only)

**You can fix this issue by following these steps**

- Uninstall node.js completely.
- Install [nvm (Node version manager)](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). When dealing with SPFx, it's a must. because you need multiple node.js versions installed on your computer. Instead of uninstalling and reinstalling them all the time, nvm makes it very simple to switch from one node.js version to another on-the-fly.
- Install correct version of node.js supported by SPFx 1.7.1: `nvm install 8.16.2`
- [Optional] Install any other node.js versions using `nvm install <Whatever_version_you_want>` command
- run `nvm use 8.16.2` to switch to node.js that is compatible with your old SPFx solution.
- Re-do all your steps mentioned in your post again.
- Whenever you need to switch to the different version of node, simply run `nvm use < version of node.js >`

Comment: ok thanks for the reply... i uninstall the node.js completlty .. and reinstall it from https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-node-js-npm-on-windows .. but when i trued to install the correct version for node.js i got this error `C:\Windows\System32>nvm install 8.16.2
'nvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: are you able to advice on this more.. now after uninstalling node.js my development environment breaks...

Comment: Sorry, I think this link is not what I meant to include. This is the right one: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: from where i need to download the NVM >

Comment: From here: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Comment: and which component i need to install exactly, as the link have many things to download

Comment: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.8/nvm-setup.zip

Comment: now i instlled nvm but when i tried to install `yeoman` i got this error `C:\Windows\System32>npm i -g yo@3.1.1
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v8.16.2`

Comment: you actually don't need yeoman, since you already have a project created, just skip this step

Comment: so now i should have 2 versions of node.js ? and how i can confirm this?  `C:\Windows\System32>node -v` i got
`v8.16.2`

Comment: run `nvm list` and see the list of installed node.js versions. then run `nvm use < version you want>` to use version you want. in your case its `nvm use 8.16.2`

Comment: you mean to use `nvm use <>` and not `npm use` am i correct?

Comment: yes, sorry, `nvm use` `nvm list`  instead of npm

Comment: here what i get now `C:\spfx-MyModalPopup>npm list` will get this
`npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v8.16.2`

Comment: any further advice ?

Comment: advice on what? did you see  my previous comments?

Comment: did you also see my previous comments?

Comment: Of course. So what advice do you need?

Comment: Now seems my whole dev environment is corrupted..  after i uninstall the node.js currently i am unable to run the web parts locally using `C:\spfx-MyModalPopup>gulp serve` i got
`ReferenceError: primordials is not defined`

Comment: your dev is not corrupted. you simply need to figure out how uninstall node.js correctly and reinstall nvm again. I think you are going too far from your original question now. I saw your separate question where I already gave you advice. I my original answer really has all main general steps you need.